# Spring boot reactive (Webflux) with MySql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I would develop an Spring boot application compliant with new feature Webflux. 
Does an driver JDBC for Mysql exist?

I found just driver for some NoSql DB (for ex. MongoDB).

Could you help me?
Thanks, regards.

**UPDATE:**

On official site of R2DBC project there is the drivers list: https://r2dbc.io/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually there isn't any reactive support for relational database. But not for long time since the Spring Data team is working on R2DBC, which will provide the ability to access data reactively from a relational database. Stay tuned here: https://github.com/r2dbc

**EDIT**

The first release is out, see here for more details: https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql/tags

Comment: It is 2021 and I still wait for MySQL support :( I checked the github account but not yet found. (However, in Spring website, they said r2dbc already support MSSQL, Prosgre and MySQL, how strange).

Answer (score 5):

An asynchronous driver for MySQL exists and it's called `jasync-sql`:

https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql

Answer (score 1):

No there is no reactive driver for MySQl. There is one for Postgres:

https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-client

it uses all the reactive bits from project rector (collections are return as flux). Of Course you are back to working with prepared statements. And pulling data directly from the Serch reasult.

And the one for the oracle DB:

https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/AoJ

But it uses a blocking JDBC calls and only hides the problem of behind thread pool. However it represent the current effort at Oracle to attack the problem. And it is not a trivial thing as there is a certain philosophy when working with relational databases of consistent state. That is why your query result is return all at once unlike mongodb that can return result as it comes in.

Because of that any ORM (hibernate, eclipselink) tooling is nowhere.
I think for production code we are stuck with blocking calls for now.